# EJB @Stateless + Seam @Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION) = @Stateful?

Tags: seam2, seam-conversation

Im a new SEAM developer and for sure im really enjoying the platform.

im wondering wether a stateless session bean plus conversation scope has the same semantic by stateful session bean ?

the EJB Client in this context is the seam, right ? so using conversation scope, the ejb bean used by the client ( seam component ) will be the same during the conversation, this way the state will be preserved until the conversation finish.

is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

No. *Stateless session beans always live in the stateless context.*

Answer (score 0):

I think Stateless session bean is always in Stateless scope, no way to set to Conversation scope.